# Not able to install lightbend activator for running play

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I have installed SBT and set all the paths required for it (sbt_home, fn, path) in order to support play or activator. I have also set the path for activator bin.

This is the error that I am getting:

[image: this is the error that i am getting]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [instructions](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/05/play-framework-getting-started.html).